# Apache Flink enrich actual stream with reference data

Tags: apache-flink, flink-state

I have a kafka stream of actual data that needs to be enriched using reference data.

Reference data can be fetched using API call. And any update on reference data comes on another kafka topic.

I want to fetch the whole reference data using API on startup and store in flink state.
Also update the state based on the kafka reference data update.

How can the state be shared across task slots in multiple task managers so that I can connect the actual data stream and reference data stream to do the enrichment?
This is to make sure all parallel operators have access to whole reference data and same state.

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 2):

Flink's [broadcast state pattern](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/broadcast_state/) support should work for you, as far as ensuring that all enrichment data is available to all sub-tasks.

For starting all with all API-based data, and then adding updates from Kafka, I would use Flink's [hybrid source](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/hybridsource/) support. In your `main()` method, download enrichment data from the API and save in files, then use a hybrid source that first reads from the file system, and switches to Kafka when that's complete.

Comment: Can't I pass the data from api as a datastream to coflatmap and add it to state in the open function. Will all the operators wait until this api data is written into state

Comment: The data stream will be partitioned before being sent to the `CoFlatMapFunction`, unless you run that with a parallelism of 1 (and thus poor performance). This partitioning would prevent you from fulfilling the requirement of "This is to make sure all parallel operators have access to whole reference data".

Comment: I meant pass the datastream as parameter in the constructor.

Comment: Datastreams start sending data once all of the operator open() calls have completed. So no, you can't pass the datastream as a parameter and then call it in the open() method.

Comment: How can I ensure that api data is written into state before starting actual data processing?